# ReactJS - Alert message when WebBrowser go ahead/back/refresh button clicked

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to implement a script/function in ReactJS that prevent the user **Go Back** or **Refresh** or **Go Ahead** an actual application page in ReactJS without a confirmation alert message.

My Home: localhost:3000/
Resume Page: localhost:3000/resume

If the user is in `/resume` page, and then **accidentally** or **intentional** try to refresh, go back, or go ahead using the typical WebBrowser controls, the app in ReactJS detects the action and show a alert message like: e.x ***"Wow! You're trying to leave a page, if you continue you can lose all data. Are you sure to continue?"***

¿Any idea about how to solve it?

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using pure JS. `window.onbeforeunload` as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) lets you do something before unloading the page or even cancel the event itself.

```
window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
// Your alert logic could be invoked here...
};
```

Comment: Mind you that this doesn't cover everything - i.e. if you use some hash-driven routing (e.g. `react-router`), then back button doesn't trigger `onbeforeunload` and still can cause data to be lost.